# Getting error while retrieving array from stored procedure(oracle DB)

Tags: java, oracle, plsql

I have created type first in my DB

```
CREATE or replace  TYPE notif_array AS table OF VARCHAR2(10);
```

then i have created the stored procedure

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE get_notification_id(personrole in varchar2,personid out notif_array)
is
begin
select person_id bulk collect  into personid from  exp_role_person_mapping where person_role=personrole;
exception when others then
personid:=null;
end;
```

My java code

```
        CallableStatement cs = db.createCallableStatement("begin get_next_level_dtls(?,?);end;", 0);
        cs.setObject(1,historyRow.getAttribute("ToRole").toString());
        cs.registerOutParameter(2, OracleTypes.ARRAY,"notif_array");
        cs.execute();
        String[] PersonIds = (cs.getArray(2)!=null && cs.getArray(2).getArray()!=null) ?
            (String[])cs.getArray(2).getArray():
            null;
```

It gives me error on  cs.registerOutParameter(2,OracleTypes.ARRAY,"notif_array"); it says

```
 java.sql.SQLException: invalid name pattern: APPS.notif_array
at oracle.jdbc.oracore.OracleTypeADT.initMetadata11_2(OracleTypeADT.java:888)
at oracle.jdbc.oracore.OracleTypeADT.initMetadata(OracleTypeADT.java:546)
at oracle.jdbc.oracore.OracleTypeADT.init(OracleTypeADT.java:504)
at oracle.sql.ArrayDescriptor.initPickler(ArrayDescriptor.java:2291)
at oracle.sql.ArrayDescriptor.<init>(ArrayDescriptor.java:283)
at oracle.sql.ArrayDescriptor.createDescriptor(ArrayDescriptor.java:133)
at oracle.sql.ArrayDescriptor.createDescriptor(ArrayDescriptor.java:75)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.NamedTypeAccessor.otypeFromName(NamedTypeAccessor.java:85)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.TypeAccessor.initMetadata(TypeAccessor.java:78)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CCallableStatement.allocateAccessor(T4CCallableStatement.java:652)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleCallableStatement.registerOutParameterInternal(OracleCallableStatement.java:216)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleCallableStatement.registerOutParameter(OracleCallableStatement.java:273)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleCallableStatementWrapper.registerOutParameter(OracleCallableStatementWrapper.java:1809)
at weblogic.jdbc.wrapper.CallableStatement_oracle_jdbc_driver_OracleCallableStatementWrapper.registerOutParameter(Unknown Source)
at evosys.expense.MB.PayrollSubmitExpenseBean.sendNotification(PayrollSubmitExpenseBean.java:777)
at evosys.expense.MB.PayrollSubmitExpenseBean.submitExpenseRecord(PayrollSubmitExpenseBean.java:274)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at com.sun.el.util.ReflectionUtil.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtil.java:181)
at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:289)
at com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:304)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
at javax.faces.event.MethodExpressionActionListener.processAction(MethodExpressionActionListener.java:147)
at javax.faces.event.ActionEvent.processListener(ActionEvent.java:88)
at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.component.UIXComponentBase.broadcast(UIXComponentBase.java:1127)
at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.component.UIXCommand.broadcast(UIXCommand.java:179)
at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.component.UIXComponent.broadcastInContext(UIXComponent.java:364)
at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.component.WrapperEvent.broadcastWrappedEvent(WrapperEvent.java:82)
at oracle.adf.view.rich.component.fragment.ContextSwitchingComponent$1.run(ContextSwitchingComponent.java:168)
at oracle.adf.view.rich.component.fragment.ContextSwitchingComponent._processPhase(ContextSwitchingComponent.java:510)
at oracle.adf.view.rich.component.fragment.ContextSwitchingComponent.broadcast(ContextSwitchingComponent.java:171)
at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.component.UIXComponent.broadcastInContext(UIXComponent.java:364)
at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.component.WrapperEvent.broadcastWrappedEvent(WrapperEvent.java:82)
at oracle.adf.view.rich.component.fragment.UIXInclude.broadcast(UIXInclude.java:111)
at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.component.UIXComponent.broadcastInContext(UIXComponent.java:364)
at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.component.WrapperEvent.broadcastWrappedEvent(WrapperEvent.java:82)
at oracle.adf.view.rich.component.fragment.ContextSwitchingComponent$1.run(ContextSwitchingComponent.java:168)
at oracle.adf.view.rich.component.fragment.ContextSwitchingComponent._processPhase(ContextSwitchingComponent.java:510)
at oracle.adf.view.rich.component.fragment.ContextSwitchingComponent.broadcast(ContextSwitchingComponent.java:171)
at oracle.adf.view.rich.component.fragment.UIXInclude.broadcast(UIXInclude.java:115)
at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.component.UIXComponent.broadcastInContext(UIXComponent.java:364)
at oracle.adf.view.rich.event.ProxyEvent.broadcastWrappedEvent(ProxyEvent.java:72)
at oracle.adf.view.rich.component.fragment.UIXRegion._handleProxyEvent(UIXRegion.java:933)
at oracle.adf.view.rich.component.fragment.UIXRegion.broadcast(UIXRegion.java:117)
at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.component.UIXComponent.broadcastInContext(UIXComponent.java:364)
at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.component.WrapperEvent.broadcastWrappedEvent(WrapperEvent.java:82)
at oracle.adf.view.rich.component.fragment.ContextSwitchingComponent$1.run(ContextSwitchingComponent.java:168)
at oracle.adf.view.rich.component.fragment.ContextSwitchingComponent._processPhase(ContextSwitchingComponent.java:510)
at oracle.adf.view.rich.component.fragment.ContextSwitchingComponent.broadcast(ContextSwitchingComponent.java:171)
at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.component.UIXComponent.broadcastInContext(UIXComponent.java:364)
at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.component.WrapperEvent.broadcastWrappedEvent(WrapperEvent.java:82)
at oracle.adf.view.rich.component.fragment.UIXInclude.broadcast(UIXInclude.java:111)
at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.component.UIXComponent.broadcastInContext(UIXComponent.java:364)
at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.component.WrapperEvent.broadcastWrappedEvent(WrapperEvent.java:82)
at oracle.adf.view.rich.component.fragment.ContextSwitchingComponent$1.run(ContextSwitchingComponent.java:168)
at oracle.adf.view.rich.component.fragment.ContextSwitchingComponent._processPhase(ContextSwitchingComponent.java:510)
at oracle.adf.view.rich.component.fragment.ContextSwitchingComponent.broadcast(ContextSwitchingComponent.java:171)
at oracle.adf.view.rich.component.fragment.UIXInclude.broadcast(UIXInclude.java:115)
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:790)
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1282)
at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl._invokeApplication(LifecycleImpl.java:1243)
at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl._executeInvokeApplication(LifecycleImpl.java:686)
at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl._executePhase(LifecycleImpl.java:364)
at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:227)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:650)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:286)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:260)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:137)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:350)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:25)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78)
at oracle.adf.model.servlet.ADFBindingFilter.doFilter(ADFBindingFilter.java:207)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78)
at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.webapp.rich.RegistrationFilter.doFilter(RegistrationFilter.java:105)
at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.webapp.TrinidadFilterImpl$FilterListChain.doFilter(TrinidadFilterImpl.java:529)
at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.activedata.AdsFilter.doFilter(AdsFilter.java:60)
at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.webapp.TrinidadFilterImpl$FilterListChain.doFilter(TrinidadFilterImpl.java:529)
at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.webapp.TrinidadFilterImpl._doFilterImpl(TrinidadFilterImpl.java:354)
at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.webapp.TrinidadFilterImpl.doFilter(TrinidadFilterImpl.java:232)
at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.webapp.TrinidadFilter.doFilter(TrinidadFilter.java:92)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78)
at oracle.adf.library.webapp.LibraryFilter.doFilter(LibraryFilter.java:169)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78)
at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter$1.run(JpsAbsFilter.java:141)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at oracle.security.jps.util.JpsSubject.doAsPrivileged(JpsSubject.java:315)
at oracle.security.jps.ee.util.JpsPlatformUtil.runJaasMode(JpsPlatformUtil.java:650)
at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter.runJaasMode(JpsAbsFilter.java:124)
at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter.doFilter(JpsAbsFilter.java:232)
at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsFilter.doFilter(JpsFilter.java:94)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78)
at oracle.dms.servlet.DMSServletFilter.doFilter(DMSServletFilter.java:248)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestEventsFilter.doFilter(RequestEventsFilter.java:32)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3683)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3649)
at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:326)
at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAsForUserCode(SecurityManager.java:197)
at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSecurityProvider.runAsForUserCode(WlsSecurityProvider.java:203)
at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:71)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.doSecuredExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2433)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2281)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2259)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.runInternal(ServletRequestImpl.java:1691)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1651)
at weblogic.servlet.provider.ContainerSupportProviderImpl$WlsRequestExecutor.run(ContainerSupportProviderImpl.java:270)
at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager._runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:348)
at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager.runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:333)
at weblogic.work.LivePartitionUtility.doRunWorkUnderContext(LivePartitionUtility.java:54)
at weblogic.work.PartitionUtility.runWorkUnderContext(PartitionUtility.java:41)
at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.runWorkUnderContext(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:640)
at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:406)
at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:346)
```

APPS is the name of my DB schema

i am getting another error now

```
java.sql.SQLException: ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'GET_NEXT_LEVEL_DTLS'
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored

at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:466)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:407)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:1113)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:546)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:269)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:603)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CCallableStatement.doOall8(T4CCallableStatement.java:228)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CCallableStatement.doOall8(T4CCallableStatement.java:49)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CCallableStatement.executeForRows(T4CCallableStatement.java:1000)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1316)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:5010)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.execute(OraclePreparedStatement.java:5195)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleCallableStatement.execute(OracleCallableStatement.java:10814)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.execute(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1546)
at weblogic.jdbc.wrapper.PreparedStatement.execute(PreparedStatement.java:119)
at evosys.expense.MB.PayrollSubmitExpenseBean.sendNotification(PayrollSubmitExpenseBean.java:778)
at evosys.expense.MB.PayrollSubmitExpenseBean.submitExpenseRecord(PayrollSubmitExpenseBean.java:274)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at com.sun.el.util.ReflectionUtil.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtil.java:181)
at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:289)
at com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:304)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
at javax.faces.event.MethodExpressionActionListener.processAction(MethodExpressionActionListener.java:147)
at javax.faces.event.ActionEvent.processListener(ActionEvent.java:88)
at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.component.UIXComponentBase.broadcast(UIXComponentBase.java:1127)
at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.component.UIXCommand.broadcast(UIXCommand.java:179)
at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.component.UIXComponent.broadcastInContext(UIXComponent.java:364)
at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.component.WrapperEvent.broadcastWrappedEvent(WrapperEvent.java:82)
at oracle.adf.view.rich.component.fragment.ContextSwitchingComponent$1.run(ContextSwitchingComponent.java:168)
at oracle.adf.view.rich.component.fragment.ContextSwitchingComponent._processPhase(ContextSwitchingComponent.java:510)
at oracle.adf.view.rich.component.fragment.ContextSwitchingComponent.broadcast(ContextSwitchingComponent.java:171)
at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.component.UIXComponent.broadcastInContext(UIXComponent.java:364)
at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.component.WrapperEvent.broadcastWrappedEvent(WrapperEvent.java:82)
at oracle.adf.view.rich.component.fragment.UIXInclude.broadcast(UIXInclude.java:111)
at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.component.UIXComponent.broadcastInContext(UIXComponent.java:364)
at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.component.WrapperEvent.broadcastWrappedEvent(WrapperEvent.java:82)
at oracle.adf.view.rich.component.fragment.ContextSwitchingComponent$1.run(ContextSwitchingComponent.java:168)
at oracle.adf.view.rich.component.fragment.ContextSwitchingComponent._processPhase(ContextSwitchingComponent.java:510)
at oracle.adf.view.rich.component.fragment.ContextSwitchingComponent.broadcast(ContextSwitchingComponent.java:171)
at oracle.adf.view.rich.component.fragment.UIXInclude.broadcast(UIXInclude.java:115)
at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.component.UIXComponent.broadcastInContext(UIXComponent.java:364)
at oracle.adf.view.rich.event.ProxyEvent.broadcastWrappedEvent(ProxyEvent.java:72)
at oracle.adf.view.rich.component.fragment.UIXRegion._handleProxyEvent(UIXRegion.java:933)
at oracle.adf.view.rich.component.fragment.UIXRegion.broadcast(UIXRegion.java:117)
at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.component.UIXComponent.broadcastInContext(UIXComponent.java:364)
at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.component.WrapperEvent.broadcastWrappedEvent(WrapperEvent.java:82)
at oracle.adf.view.rich.component.fragment.ContextSwitchingComponent$1.run(ContextSwitchingComponent.java:168)
at oracle.adf.view.rich.component.fragment.ContextSwitchingComponent._processPhase(ContextSwitchingComponent.java:510)
at oracle.adf.view.rich.component.fragment.ContextSwitchingComponent.broadcast(ContextSwitchingComponent.java:171)
at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.component.UIXComponent.broadcastInContext(UIXComponent.java:364)
at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.component.WrapperEvent.broadcastWrappedEvent(WrapperEvent.java:82)
at oracle.adf.view.rich.component.fragment.UIXInclude.broadcast(UIXInclude.java:111)
at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.component.UIXComponent.broadcastInContext(UIXComponent.java:364)
at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.component.WrapperEvent.broadcastWrappedEvent(WrapperEvent.java:82)
at oracle.adf.view.rich.component.fragment.ContextSwitchingComponent$1.run(ContextSwitchingComponent.java:168)
at oracle.adf.view.rich.component.fragment.ContextSwitchingComponent._processPhase(ContextSwitchingComponent.java:510)
at oracle.adf.view.rich.component.fragment.ContextSwitchingComponent.broadcast(ContextSwitchingComponent.java:171)
at oracle.adf.view.rich.component.fragment.UIXInclude.broadcast(UIXInclude.java:115)
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:790)
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1282)
at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl._invokeApplication(LifecycleImpl.java:1243)
at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl._executeInvokeApplication(LifecycleImpl.java:686)
at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl._executePhase(LifecycleImpl.java:364)
at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:227)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:650)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:286)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:260)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:137)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:350)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:25)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78)
at oracle.adf.model.servlet.ADFBindingFilter.doFilter(ADFBindingFilter.java:207)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78)
at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.webapp.rich.RegistrationFilter.doFilter(RegistrationFilter.java:105)
at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.webapp.TrinidadFilterImpl$FilterListChain.doFilter(TrinidadFilterImpl.java:529)
at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.activedata.AdsFilter.doFilter(AdsFilter.java:60)
at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.webapp.TrinidadFilterImpl$FilterListChain.doFilter(TrinidadFilterImpl.java:529)
at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.webapp.TrinidadFilterImpl._doFilterImpl(TrinidadFilterImpl.java:354)
at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.webapp.TrinidadFilterImpl.doFilter(TrinidadFilterImpl.java:232)
at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.webapp.TrinidadFilter.doFilter(TrinidadFilter.java:92)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78)
at oracle.adf.library.webapp.LibraryFilter.doFilter(LibraryFilter.java:169)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78)
at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter$1.run(JpsAbsFilter.java:141)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at oracle.security.jps.util.JpsSubject.doAsPrivileged(JpsSubject.java:315)
at oracle.security.jps.ee.util.JpsPlatformUtil.runJaasMode(JpsPlatformUtil.java:650)
at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter.runJaasMode(JpsAbsFilter.java:124)
at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter.doFilter(JpsAbsFilter.java:232)
at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsFilter.doFilter(JpsFilter.java:94)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78)
at oracle.dms.servlet.DMSServletFilter.doFilter(DMSServletFilter.java:248)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestEventsFilter.doFilter(RequestEventsFilter.java:32)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3683)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3649)
at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:326)
at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAsForUserCode(SecurityManager.java:197)
at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSecurityProvider.runAsForUserCode(WlsSecurityProvider.java:203)
at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:71)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.doSecuredExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2433)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2281)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2259)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.runInternal(ServletRequestImpl.java:1691)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1651)
at weblogic.servlet.provider.ContainerSupportProviderImpl$WlsRequestExecutor.run(ContainerSupportProviderImpl.java:270)
at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager._runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:348)
at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager.runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:333)
at weblogic.work.LivePartitionUtility.doRunWorkUnderContext(LivePartitionUtility.java:54)
at weblogic.work.PartitionUtility.runWorkUnderContext(PartitionUtility.java:41)
at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.runWorkUnderContext(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:640)
at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:406)
at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:346)
```

Comment: Can you please add the complete stacktrace please?

Comment: @Jens Done that.

Comment: I have also used java.sql.Types.Array instead of OracleTypes.Array. but still the error persist

Comment: The procedure you're calling isn't the one you've showed us - but presumably both have the same argument types? Also why are you using `setObject()` instead of `setString()`?

Comment: now i am using that @AlexPoole. now i am getting another error

Comment: @RahulGulwani - was that supposed to be a comment on my answer, or a reply to my previous comment? What error do you get now?

Comment: @RahulGulwani - well as I already said, the procedure you are calling is not the same one you showed the definition for...

Comment: Yes. @AlexPoole. Problem has been resolved Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use the same case that the object name appears with in the data dictionary. As you created it with [an unquoted identifier](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements008.htm), it is in the dictionary as `NOTIF_ARRAY` not `notif_array`. You can verify that with:

```
select owner, object_name
from all_objects where object_type = 'TYPE'
and lower(object_name) = 'notif_array';
```

So you need to use:

```
cs.registerOutParameter(2, OracleTypes.ARRAY, "NOTIF_ARRAY");
```

(Incidentally, the error you get comes from the thin driver; with the OCI driver you get a *slightly* more helpful ORA-04043 object does not exist error).

Also the procedure you are calling is `get_next_level_dtls`, not the one you showed the definition for, `get_notification_id`. If both procedures have the same argument types that may work but not give the results you expect; but if `get_next_level_dtls` has different argument types you'll get a PLS-00306 error.

Unless you've changed the names inconsistently while posting your question, which looks unlikely, change your call to the right procedure:

```
CallableStatement cs = db.createCallableStatement("begin get_notification_id(?,?);end;", 0);
```

I assume `db` is your own class wrapper for connection management.